# Deformation of topological spaces.

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

I have the following problem: calculate the foundamental group of $X=\mathbb R^3-(\{(x,y,z) | x^2+y^2=1, z=0\}\cup\{(x,y,z)|x=y=0\})$.

I can visualize a deformation that brings $X$ onto a torus. So being the foundamental group invariant under retraction this two spaces have the same   $\pi_1$$: \pi_1(X)\cong \pi_1(S^1\times S^1)\cong \mathbb Z\times \mathbb Z. $If I am not wrong, can someone help me to explicit the retraction? I need to write it.

Comment: X is path connected.

Comment: I missed the $\mathbb R^3 - \cdots$ Sorry!

Comment: Don't worry.  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a diret formula, see [this](http://math.uchicago.edu/~may/REU2014/REUPapers/Linov.pdf) paper (Proposition 2.3) which I will reproduce:

which uses cyllindrical co-ordinates $r,\theta,z$ and excludes the $z$-axis and points of the form $(1,\theta,0)$. In this case, $\rho:=\sqrt{(r-1)^2+z^2}$ is nonvanishing, so the function
$$f_t(r,\theta,z)=(\theta,(1-t)r+t(r-1)/2\rho+t,(1-t)z+zt/2\rho) $$

which allegedly has image torus with radius 1/2 whose central circle is the unit one inthe $xy$ plane.

Example 4 [here](http://www.math3ma.com/mathema/2016/4/18/clever-homotopy-equivalences) is also very nice. The idea is that $\mathbb R^2 \setminus \{pt\}$ is a circle, so considering a plane swept around the $z$-axis, this is just $S^1 \times S^1$